Regridding netcdf file using rasterio in Python
I'm trying to regrid a NetCDF file to a higher resolution using rasterio but the package couldn't parse the data. The same thing happened when I tried to do it with cdo. The latter suggests the error might be due to the naming of the dimensions but rasterio did not give such an indication. So, I'm not sure where the problem lies.
Here's my code:
from rasterio.enums import Resampling
import xarray as xr

yt_fwi = xr.open_dataset("/file_path/yt_fwi_redo.nc")
upscale_factor = 10
new_width = yt_fwi.rio.width * upscale_factor
new_height = yt_fwi.rio.height * upscale_factor

resamp_fwi = yt_fwi.rio.reproject(yt_fwi.rio.crs, shape=(int(new_height), int(new_width)), resampling=Resampling.nearest)


rasterio._err.CPLE_AppDefinedError: Invalid band count : 438700. Maximum allowed currently is 65536. Define GDAL_MAX_BAND_COUNT to a higher level if it is a legitimate number.

Here's a sample data

Opening your sample file with R package ncdfCF, I get this:
> yt <- open_ncdf("~/Downloads/yt_fwi_redo.nc")
> yt
<Dataset> yt_fwi_redo 
Resource   : ~/Downloads/yt_fwi_redo.nc 
Format     : netcdf4 
Conventions: (not indicated) 
Keep open  : FALSE 
Has groups : FALSE 

Variables:
 name     units data_type axes           
 lon_bnds       NC_DOUBLE bnds, lon, time
 fwi      1     NC_DOUBLE lon, lat, time 
 ffmc     1     NC_DOUBLE lon, lat, time 
 dmc      1     NC_DOUBLE lon, lat, time 
 dc       1     NC_DOUBLE lon, lat, time 
 isi      1     NC_DOUBLE lon, lat, time 
 bui      1     NC_DOUBLE lon, lat, time 
 TEMP           NC_DOUBLE lon, lat, time 
 RH             NC_DOUBLE lon, lat, time 
 RAIN           NC_DOUBLE lon, lat, time 
 WIND           NC_DOUBLE lon, lat, time 

Axes:
 id axis name     long_name length values                                        unit                          
 0  T    time               438700 [2020-03-01 12:00:00 ... 2060-09-30 12:00:00] days since 2015-01-01T12:00:00
 1  Y    lat      Latitude       4 [59.99702 ... 68.36776]                       degrees_north                 
 3       lon                     6 [-137.8125 ... -123.75]                                                     
 4       days_wDC                5 [day-2, day-1, day, day+1, day+2]                                           
 2       bnds                    2 [1 ... 2]                                                                   

Attributes:
 id name                type    length value                                             
  0 experiment_id       NC_CHAR   6    ssp245                                            
  1 table_id            NC_CHAR   3    day                                               
  2 source_id           NC_CHAR   7    CanESM5                                           
  3 variant_label       NC_CHAR   9    r10i1p1f1                                         
  4 grid_label          NC_CHAR   2    gn                                                
  5 variable_id         NC_CHAR   3    fwi                                               
  6 info                NC_CHAR  49    Canadian Fire Weather Index calculated for CMIP6. 
  7 method              NC_CHAR 151    Computation is based on the equations from Wang...
  8 contact             NC_CHAR  45    Yann Quilcaille <yann.quilcaille@env.ethz.ch>     
  9 warning             NC_CHAR  48    This variable is not an official CMIP6 variable.  
 10 warning_method_init NC_CHAR 100    The FWI has been initialized by the common way:...
> 
> yt[["lat"]]
<Latitude axis> [1] lat
Long name: Latitude 
Length   : 4
Axis     : Y 
Values   : 59.99702, 62.78735, 65.57761, 68.36776 degrees_north
Bounds   : 58.611113, 61.402581, 64.1942, 66.986027 
         : 61.402581, 64.1942, 66.986027, 69.778146 

Attributes:
 id name          type      length value        
 0  _FillValue    NC_DOUBLE  1     NaN          
 1  bounds        NC_CHAR    8     lat_bnds     
 2  units         NC_CHAR   13     degrees_north
 3  axis          NC_CHAR    1     Y            
 4  long_name     NC_CHAR    8     Latitude     
 5  standard_name NC_CHAR    8     latitude     
>
> yt[["lon"]]
<Generic numeric axis> [3] lon
Length   : 6
Axis     :  
Values   : -137.8125, -135, -132.1875, -129.375, -126.5625, -123.75 
Bounds   : (not set)

Attributes:
 id name       type      length value
 0  _FillValue NC_DOUBLE 1      NaN  

The "time" dimension of your data set reports 438,700 days from 2020-03-01 to 2060-09-30; it is based on the CanESM5 model of climate projections. That is problematic because there are only about 16,000 days over that 41 year period. There are further problems with the file.
Note that the "lon" axis is missing some crucial attributes (compare with "lat" axis), specifically the "bounds" attribute. This appears to be the cause of your cdo troubles:
my@Patricks-MacBook-Pro ~ % cdo -remapbil,r60x40 ~/Downloads/yt_fwi_redo.nc ~/test.nc
cdi  warning (cdf_read_coordinates): Time varying grid y-bounds unsupported, skipped!

cdo    remapbil (Abort): Unsupported generic coordinates (Variable: lon_bnds)!

And that is followed by a long list of HDF5 errors.
It appears that your file is corrupt. If not, contact the person indicated in the global attributes for support.

@ptrick, the original data ranged from 1800 to 2100, but I only needed data from 2020 to 2060. So, I concatenated the whole data and extracted the needed timeline. I used both array and cdo to concatenate them, which gave a similar outcome but with those incorrect numbers of days. Following your comment, I checked the number of days in the original files, and they seem correct. So, the problem must have come from concatenating the files. I will try and troubleshoot the concatenation process. Thanks for catching the problem.

The "time" information is encoded as offset values, incrementing by 1 each day (namely: the resolution of the "time" dimension). When I look at the values of the offsets I note that each unique value occurs exactly 50 times, with the sequence recycling. Could it be that you extracted the "time" dimension but not the actual data variables? In that case the "time" dimension is recycled to reach the dimension length of the data.

The problem was that I received 50 files, and each of them was an ensemble, but I thought the files were broken down by timelines. So, I essentially concatenated 50 ensembles. That was why the unique values occurred 50 times. I shouldn't have concatenated them in the first place.
